# How to setup SSL certificate for Genie.jl app

Tags: ssl, julia, ssl-certificate, genie.jl

I have developed a simple webpage using Genie.jl. I am trying to deploy it in the internet using hostname from [noip](https://www.noip.com). I applied port forwarding and tried deploying without SSL certificate and it worked. Is there a way to deploy Genie.jl app using SSL certificate i.e. how to get a https connection between my server and client.

Thank you

Comment: https://letsencrypt.org/

Answer (score 0):

One way is to get a free SSL certificate from Let's Encrypt. Then, configure Nginx and [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/pages/about) on your server. Nginx will act as a reverse proxy, handling SSL, while Certbot will help manage and automatically renew your Let's Encrypt certificates.

Point Nginx to your Genie app and set it up to handle SSL termination and forward secure requests to your app.

In your `Genie.jl` code, create the HTTP server with SSL support using the `HTTP.jl` library. Specify the path to your Let's Encrypt certificate files in the server configuration.Ensure your router/firewall forwards incoming HTTPS (port 443) traffic to your server.